# Settings for SMTP while sending mail in background

Tags: iphone

iphone× 117661

In this statement Smtpout.servername.net,

what would be the exact entries?I am pretty much confused.I am using gmail.Please clarify.....

//the guts of the message.

```
SKPSMTPMessage *testMsg = [[SKPSMTPMessage alloc] init];
testMsg.fromEmail = @"youremail@email.com";
testMsg.toEmail = @"targetemailaddress@email.com";
testMsg.relayHost = @"smtpout.yourserver.net";
testMsg.requiresAuth = YES;
testMsg.login = @"yourusername@email.com";
testMsg.pass = @"yourPassWord";
testMsg.subject = @"This is the email subject line";
testMsg.wantsSecure = YES; // smtp.gmail.com doesn't work without TLS!
```

This code I have used ,Here in `testMsg.relayHost = @"smtpout.yourserver.net"`;

what entries would be used for smtpOut and "Your server"

Answer (score 0):

```
testMsg.relayHost = @"smtp.gmail.com"
```

This is what you should type.